# "of it" vs. "its"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

I have the following sentence:

> ... the root of the document is counted as the beginning of the context and the anchor node marks the **ending of it**.

I thought I may say it as:

> ... the root of the document is counted as the beginning of the context and the anchor node marks **its ending** (or maybe **its end**).

However the first one seems better.

In general is "its" an equivalent for "of it"? What is the application of each?

Answer (score 2):

I would use *end*:

> ... the root of the document is counted as the beginning of the context and the anchor node marks the **end** of it.

[***ending***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/ending) is different as it indicates some passage of events:

> The movie was *ending*, so decided to go to a coffee shop.

In your example *end* is a fixed point. Same way as you would say "end of the tunnel" not "ending of the tunnel".

You could use *its end*, but since you already said *beginning of*, *end of* matches it and sounds better.

Comment: Thank you, you right, you say it is usually (beginning, end)? cause I thought if it is "beginning" then that is "ending".

Comment: It is different. You can say "The movie is beginning" and "The movie is ending", but as a noun its "the beginning of ..." and "the end of ...".

Comment: Thank you, however in your post you didn't say much about the general difference of "of it" and "its"